# Can I pass a List<myclass> to a button click event?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, button

I'd like to add another member to a List (in MainForm) when a button (in formA) is clicked.

I have a class called "Trips" which contains two string members for storing.

I created a List in the MainForm:

```
List<Trips> alltrip = new List<Trips>() { new Trips("Trip 1", "March"), 
                                          new Trips("Trip 2", "May")};
```

I passed the List to FormA and then I thought that I can use *alltrip* in the button click event. But it returned an error, saying it couldn't find *alltrip*, so I tried pass it to the button like the following.

```
    Trips newTrip = new Trips();
    private void AddTripConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, List<Trips> alltrip) 
    {　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　//I add the List here
        newTrip.Name = AddTripNametxt.Text;
        newTrip.Time = AddTripTimetxt.Text;
        alltrip.Add(newTrip);
    }
```

So far it looked good for me, but then another error occurred in this line in the Designer.cs:

```
 this.AddTripConfirm.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.AddTripConfirm_Click);
```

It says that "No overload for 'AddTripConfirm_click' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler.'" As I am quite new to C# I cannot think of any solution and struggled to find a satisfying answer from similar questions.

Please help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you pass allTrips to FormA? You should save a reference to it in the form so you can access it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you passed the list to `FormA`. I assume you did this via the constructor.

So simply store this list in a member variable of your `FormA`:

```
public partial class FormA : Form
{
    private List<Trips> _allTrips; // a member variable

    public FormA(List<Trips> allTrips)
    {
         // store allTrips in _allTrips
         _allTrips = allTrips;
        InitializeComponents();
    }
```

Now you can access the list via the member variable in your event handler:

```
private void AddTripConfirm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　
    Trips newTrip = new Trips();
    newTrip.Name = AddTripNametxt.Text;
    newTrip.Time = AddTripTimetxt.Text;
    _allTrips.Add(newTrip); // use the member _allTrips
}
```

---

Since you store a reference to the list, the added trip is also available in your main form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pass `alltrip` to `FromA` in the constructor you will need to add a class variable to access it i.e:

```
private List<Trips> _alltrip;

public FormA(List<Trips> alltrip)
{
    _alltrip = alltrip;
}
```

Then when you need to use the variable just use `_alltrip`.